# Eclipse plugin junit-tools generated code with @MethodRef, but is undefined

Tags: eclipse, junit

I installed junit-tools for Eclipse to ease JUnit test creation. The test class the tool generated has a @MethodRef annotation, but it cannot be resolved and I cannot find the jar file or even better the Maven dependency to add. I do not know what the fully qualified package name is either. The problem is with the generated file before I make any modifications to it.

About the Plugin:
http://junit-tools.org/index.php
Plugin name: org.junit.tools
Version: 1.1.0.201811090440
Plugin-Id: org.junit.tools

Eclipse Version:
Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
Build id: 20180917-1800

The offending code is C:\eclipse-workspaces\jdbvc\dbvcs\src\test\java\com\enormacorp\dbvcs\model\ConnectionInformationTest.java

```
package com.enormacorp.dbvcs.model;

import javax.annotation.Generated;

import org.junit.Test;

@Generated(value = "org.junit-tools-1.1.0")
public class ConnectionInformationTest {

    private ConnectionInformation createTestSubject() {
        return new ConnectionInformation();
    }

    @MethodRef(name = "getJdbcDriverClassName", signature = "()QString;")
    @Test
    public void testGetJdbcDriverClassName() throws Exception {
        ConnectionInformation testSubject;
        String result;

        // default test
        testSubject = createTestSubject();
        result = testSubject.getJdbcDriverClassName();
    }

    @MethodRef(name = "setJdbcDriverClassName", signature = "(QString;)V")
    @Test
    public void testSetJdbcDriverClassName() throws Exception {
        ConnectionInformation testSubject;
        String jdbcDriverClassName = "";

        // default test
        testSubject = createTestSubject();
        testSubject.setJdbcDriverClassName(jdbcDriverClassName);
    }
}
```

pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.enormacorp.dbvcs</groupId>
    <artifactId>main</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>com.enormacorp.dbvcs.main</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Eclipse Error:
MethodRef cannot be resolved to a type

In the Java Build Path in Eclipse for this project I only have the JRE system library and the maven dependencies.

I want this to resolve whatever classes the tool generates. My first choice would be to add a Maven test scope dependency. My second choice would be to explicitly add whatever jar defines @MethodRef to the build path.

Answer (score 0):

It's missing the Junit-tools jar file.
Maven dependency doesn't work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.praqma</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-tools</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

So Download dependent jars files from "http://junit-tools.org/index.php/getting-started" and put them in the classpath.
[image]